# Inserir DBLookupComboBox na coluna do DBGRid do delphi

Tags: delphi

Boa tarde amigos, gostaria de saber se é possivel inserir em determinada coluna do dbGrid do delphi (XE8), um DBLookupComboBox . No caso, quando o usuario clicar no registro da coluna, o DBLookupComboBox iria mostrar os registro ... Seria possivel ?

Comment: FMX ou VCL? Para a VCL as colunas do DBGrid contam com uma propriedade chamada [PickList](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn.PickList), esse propriedade é um TStrings que quando você definir vai mostrar um combo na coluna quando o usuário clicar. Para salvar os valores você pode usar o DataChange validando o Field, por exemplo.

Comment: Bom dia amigo, consegui resolver meu problema mudando a propriedade ButtonStyle da coluna, no caso, alterei ela para cbsEllipsis ... Mas muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Poderia postar como resolveu ? ou poderia fechar a pergunta por favor, obrigado!